# How to set openmpi to the right path?

Tags: python, mpi, openmpi

I have installed and compiled openmpi on Ubuntu then I added path to `.bashrc` but the path is not correct from terminal:

```
toufik@toufik-PORTEGE-R30-A:~$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:'opt/openmpi/lib'
toufik@toufik-PORTEGE-R30-A:~$ export PATH=$PATH:'/opt/openmpi/bin' 
toufik@toufik-PORTEGE-R30-A:~$ which mpirun
/usr/bin/mpirun
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding your dirs to the beginning of the path:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH='opt/openmpi/lib':$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH='/opt/openmpi/bin':$PATH
```

See here for more info:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path